# VI curve varistor and compere between varistor and arrestor

Tags: power-electronics, protection, electric-machine, mov, varistor

why we need  to connect arrestor in parallel with varistor in some circuit ? and we know both is work to protect against high voltage?
like this pic.[image]

Comment: Well, what do *you* think?

Comment: may be split the power dissipation .cuz the varistor damage under very high voltage!!!

Comment: but i said we can put just arrestor why we connect in parallel with varistor??

Comment: so, with the varistor not working with high voltage, and the spark gap *only* working under high voltage – can you see the point?

Comment: yeah, i see, that's mean arrestor doesn't work during fault if  the voltage less than varistor voltage .